# How to program a dice race

Tags: java

I'm taking a programming II class in which we've been working on programming classes. Now we've been assigned homework to write a driver class to incorporate these classes. The homework states

> Using the die, dice, and player classes completed in class, write a
>   driver class to have three players taking turns rolling the dice.
>   First player to accumulate a total score of 35 or more is the winner."
>   For example, if player 1 rolls a 3, their score is 3. Then player 2
>   rolls. Then player 3. As each player rolls, their roll is added to
>   their previous score.

I've started writing it, but have been given the error that several items in my program cannot be resolved to a type. I also have absolutely no idea how to even begin creating a loop to do what is being asked. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceRace {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Player player1;
        Player player2;
        Player player3;
        Dice dice;
        Scanner keyboard;

        keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        dice=new Dice();

        System.out.print("First player's name: ");
            player1=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Second player's name: ");
            player2=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Third player's name: ");
            player3=keyboard.next();


        }//Ending bracket of method main

}//Ending bracket of class DiceRace
```

Comment: Presumably your Dice class have some kind of roll method that returns a value, and maybe the Player class holds a score? You should look into the different loop constructs (`for` and `while`) which are what you need to solve to exercise. As it stands the question has too little information for a good answer to be possible. (It's too broad - too many possible solutions; too little is known about your classes)

Comment: You have no `Player` class imported? Or `keyboard.next()` does not return a `Player` object

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a beginner. You should do some tutorials or stuff like that to know the basics :) Also, if you start getting familiar with an IDE (like Eclipse) then programming will be far more easy for you as IDEs can give you detailed descriptions of errors, even while writing the code.

In your above example you need to create two classes by yourself `Dice` and `Player`, as they are not in `Java` by default.

The method `keyboard.next()` reads an input from the console and returns it as object of the type `String`, not `Player`. Thus, you can not assign the variable `player1` the result, a `String`.

What you probably want is a `Player` object having a member variable `String name`. Here's an example:

```
public final class Player {
    private String mName;

    public Player(final String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this in your `main-method`:

```
player1 = new Player(keyboard.next());
System.out.println("Name of player1 is: " + player1.getName());
```

Next you probably want a `Dice` to have a `roll` method:

```
public final class Dice() {
    private Random mRandom;

    public Dice() {
        mRandom = new Random();
    }

    public int roll() {
        // Returns a random number between 1 and 6 (inclusive)
        return mRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `main` you can do:

```
Dice dice = new Dice();
System.out.println("Let's roll the dice: " dice.roll());
```

Now to the games logic, let's keep it very simple, beginner friendly:

```
int player1Score = 0;
int player2Score = 0;
int player3Score = 0;

boolean finished = false;
boolean player1One = false;
boolean player2One = false;
boolean player3One = false;

// 0 is first player, 1 second and 2 third
int currentPlayer = 0;

while(!finished) {
    int rollValue = dice.roll();

    if (currentPlayer == 0) {
        player1Score += rollValue;
    } else if (currentPlayer == 1) {
        player2Score += rollValue;
    } else {
        player3Score += rollValue;
    }

    player1One = player1Score >= 35;
    player2One = player2Score >= 35;
    player3One = player3Score >= 35;
    finished = player1One || player2One || player3One;

    // Increment and modulo 3 (numbers between 0 and 2)
    currentPlayer = ((currentPlayer + 1) % 3);
}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 methods, for each player, and a method that plays the game. In each player's method, it first calls the play method with a parameter containing the player name, and the play method prints it out so that the player knows who's turn it is. once the play method is done, it will call the next player method, then the player after that, and finally back to player 1.